Can free shipping be set up only for specific postal codes?
Is it possible to configure free shipping in our Magento online shop for specific postal codes only? We would like to offer free shipping as a promotional option, but restrict it to certain areas to manage shipping costs effectively. What steps do we need to follow to set this up, and are there any specific settings or extensions recommended for this purpose?

You can add the condition in cart rule to give free shipping based on postcode
https://prnt.sc/DzU4fRaON8Sf
